# Read first element and next element from a file SCALA

Tags: scala

I am reading a file that contain 277272 lines with Int triples (s,p,o) like:

```
10,44,22
10,47,12
15,38,3
15,41,30
16,38,5
16,44,15
16,47,18
22,38,21
22,41,42
34,44,40
34,47,36
40,38,39
40,41,42
45,38,27
45,41,30
46,44,45
46,47,48
```

From this file I create a Random access file object in order to navigate trough this file. However I want to extract some specific values that are in the first column, an example can be that I want to extract the values of the row that contains 16 in the first column, then I choose a pointer that is in the half, something like:

```
var lengthfile = (file.length().asInstanceOf[Int])
var initpointer = lengthfile/2
```

Then I analize if the first value is 16, if not I did a procedure to move the pointer to the nextlines, or as in this case in the back lines. Once I detect that the first value is 16, I need to know if it was in the first row, the sceond or the last one.  The functions that I present here are to get the first value of the line where I have the pointer, and to know the first value from the next line.

```
def firstvalue(pf: Int, file:RandomAccessFile): List[Int] ={
    //val file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r")
    var pointer = pf
    var flag = true
    var fline = Option("a")
    if (pointer <= file.length()-1){
      file.seek(pointer)
      fline = Option(file.readLine)
    }
    else {
      pointer = file.length().toInt-12
      file.seek(pointer)
      fline = Option(file.readLine)
    }
    while (flag)
    {
      if (fline.get != "")
      {
        if (pointer == 0)
        {
          file.seek(pointer)
          fline = Option(file.readLine)
          pointer -= 1
          flag = false
        }
        else{
          pointer -= 1
          file.seek(pointer)
          fline = Option(file.readLine)
        }
      }
      else if (fline.get == ""){
        flag = false
      }
    }
    pointer += 1
    file.seek(pointer)
    val line = Option(file.readLine)
    val spl = line.get.split(',')
    val p = spl.apply(0).toInt
    //file.close()
    val l = pointer :: p :: Nil
    l
  }
  //def nextvalue(pf: Int, filename:String): List[Int] = {
    //val file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r")
  def nextvalue(pf: Int, file:RandomAccessFile): List[Int] = {
    //val file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r")
    var pointer = pf
    var p = 0
    var flag = true
    var lastline = false
    var fline = Option ("a")
    if (pointer <= file.length()-1){
      file.seek(pointer)
      fline = Option(file.readLine)
    }

    //fline = Option(file.readLine)
    while (flag){
      if (fline.get != "")
      {
        if (fline == None)
        {
          flag = false
          lastline = true
        }
        else{
          pointer = file.getFilePointer.toInt
          fline = Option(file.readLine)
          flag = false

        }
      }
      else if (fline.get == ""){
        fline = Option(file.readLine)
        flag = false
      }
    }
    if (lastline == false)
    {

      //file.close()
      if (fline != None){
        val spl = fline.get.split(',')
        p = spl.apply(0).toInt
      }


    }
    val l = pointer :: p :: Nil
    l
  }
```

However I have a prformance problem, because I am reading character by character, I am trying to fix that during a lot of days, and I don't have a solution. I don't know If perhaps the file object have a function to read back lines, or something that allows to me improve this code? How can I improve this code?

Comment: Some conditionals are to detect if I am in the first lin of the file, or if I am in the end ofthe file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Source
   .fromFile(file)
   .getLines
   .zipWithIndex
   .filter(_._1.startsWith("16,"))
```

Will give you all lines, that start with "16", along with their indices in the file. That should be faster then seeking back and forth ...